# How can I check whether employee is registered to receive benefits?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

We have a form that passes 3 parameters, fname, lname, hiredate to another page that are used to check whether an individual is an employee of the company.

The code below does the verification based on those 3 parameters.

```
Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT fname,lname,hiredate (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comp WHERE comp.emp_ID = e.emp_ID) AS [exists], b.* FROM dbo.EMP e LEFT OUTER JOIN comp b ON e.emp_id=b.emp_id WHERE e.fname Like '%" & Request.QueryString("fname") & "%' And e.lname Like '%" & Request.QueryString("lname") & "%' And e.hiredate = '" & Request.QueryString("hiredate") & "'"
```

If the check confirms that this individual is indeed an employee, the next code checks his/her eligibity to receive benefits:

```
If myDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

    Dim listOfBenefits = New List(Of String) ( { _
        "CT07B", "CT081", "CT083", "SG09A", "SG10", "SC11A", "SG23", "SG23A", "SG27" _
    })

    If Not listOfBenefits.Contains(txtBenefits.Text) Then
        blMsg.Text = "This employee is not eligible to receive any of the listed benefits yet."
    End If

End If
```

This works very well so far.

Now, we are trying to add another check to verify if a particular employee has been registered for any benefits.

If the employee is not registered for any of the benefits, then no need to check for his or her eligibility.

If, on the other hand, the employee has registered for some benefits, then we check whether he/she is eligible for any of the listed benefits above.

My check so far isn't working as the check to determine if the employee is registered for any benefits is being ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the updated code that includes check for registration for benefits.

```
 Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT fname,lname,hiredate, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comp WHERE comp.emp_ID = e.emp_ID) AS [exists], b.* FROM dbo.EMP e LEFT OUTER JOIN comp b ON e.emp_id=b.emp_id WHERE e.fname Like '%" & Request.QueryString("fname") & "%' And e.lname Like '%" & Request.QueryString("lname") & "%' And e.hiredate = '" & Request.QueryString("hiredate") & "'"

If myDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

    ' Ok, this individual is an employee, let's check to see if s/he has registered for any benefits.
    benefitSQL = "SELECT fname, lname, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM benefits WHERE benefits.emp_ID = e.emp_ID) AS [exists], b.* FROM dbo.EMP e LEFT OUTER JOIN benefits b ON e.emp_id=b.emp_id "

    If CInt(exists.Value) > 0 Then
        ' Then employee has some benefits. Now, check whether one of those benefits is on the list below. '

        Dim listOfBenefits = New List(Of String) ( { _
            "CT07B", "CT081", "CT083", "SG09A", "SG10", "SC11A", "SG23", "SG23A", "SG27" _
        } )

        If Not listOfBenefits.Contains(txtBenefits.Text) Then
            lblMsg.Text = "This employee is not eligible to receive any of the listed benefits yet."
        End If
    Else

        lblMsg.Text = "This employee has not registered for any benefits yet."   
    End If
 End If
```

The SQL, formatted:

```
SELECT
    fname,
    lname,
    hiredate,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            Comp
        WHERE
            comp.emp_ID = e.emp_ID
    ) AS [exists],
    b.*
FROM
    dbo.EMP e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN comp b ON e.emp_id = b.emp_id
WHERE
    e.fname LIKE %@fname And e.lname LIKE %@lname%
    AND
    e.hiredate = @hiredate
```

Comment: how do you execute the benefits query executescalar or executesql.

Comment: Your code is wiiiiiiide open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: The code I showed is just a snippet of a very long code.

I am just hoping that someone will can see if my logic is off.

I can worry about the injection later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the data, but you want to constrain by the data:

```
SELECT
    e.fname,
    e.lname,
    e.hiredate
FROM
    dbo.EMP e
WHERE
    e.fname LIKE %@fname And e.lname LIKE %@lname%
    AND
    e.hiredate = @hiredate
    AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            Comp
        WHERE
            comp.emp_ID = e.emp_ID
    )
```

You could also inner join the tables:

```
SELECT
    e.fname,
    e.lname,
    e.hiredate,
    c.*
FROM
    dbo.EMP e
    INNER JOIN Comp c ON e.emp_ID = c.emp_ID
WHERE
    e.fname LIKE %@fname And e.lname LIKE %@lname%
    AND
    e.hiredate = @hiredate
```